# Add audio to Powerpoint - make playback stable against user actions

Tags: microsoft-powerpoint-2007

I have a Powerpoint 2007 presentation to which I've added an audio file. I embedded the .wav file in the ppt, selected 'play across slides', then used the Rehearse Presentation feature to time the slides to the audio.

This works to a degree - users can playback the powerpoint, with the slides initially correctly timed. However, I found that the playback is very fragile. In particular, if the user at any point manually clicks forward or back while the slideshow is playing, or clicks in another window causing Powerpoint to lose the focus, then playback subsquently goes wrong. Usually, powerpoint continues playing the audio as if nothing had happened, but no longer automatically forwards the slides in time to the audio - and I haven't found any way of recovering short of closing powerpoint, and reopening and playing the presentation again from the beginning.  I'm pretty sure that'll be confusing to anyone watching the presentation.

Is there any way to make the presentation less fragile against users clicking?  In other words to make sure that powerpoint continues to show the correct slides at the correct times synced to the audio?

Comment: All PowerPoint is doing is starting the audio file - think of it as playing on a stereo sitting beside the PC. If you manually change slides outside of your sequence, that has no effect on the audio. So the answer is probably not to click.

Comment: OK fair enough, thanks. Shame, I thought powerpoint would've been more powerful than that for embedded audio. I'll have to tell users not to click anywhere for the whole hour!